# How to sort data after using ORDER BY DECODE alphabetically?

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT city, country_id
FROM locations
ORDER BY DECODE(country_id, 'CA', 1, 'US', 2);
```

I need to sort the rest of the country_id's by alphabetically after it shows something like;

```
CA
CA
US
US
US
ETC ALPHABETICAL ORDER
```

HELP!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two columns in `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT city, country_id
FROM locations
ORDER BY CASE country_id WHEN 'CA' THEN 1 WHEN 'US' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END, country_id;
```

Cheers!!